# How do I regenerate the packages directory for a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I recently created a **C++ Visual Studio 2017 unit test project (vcxproj) based on Google Test**. I used *File/New/Project/Installed/Visual C++/Test/Google Test*.

This created a **package.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <package id="Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="native" />
  </packages>
```

It also created a `packages` directory in my solution and places the `googletest` package in it. This directory contains binary libraries (no source code) so I did not add the `packages` directory to revision control. My assumption was that Visual Studio would re-download the package if it was missing (using nuget or something).

However when I clone the repository and start fresh, the unit test project refuses to open ("load failed") because the packages directory mentioned in one of its import statements is absent:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.0\build\native\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.targets" />
```

I looked at this article, which seems to contain some tips:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

They recommend to enable "Automatically check for missing packages during build". My checkbox was already checked, so I am guessing it can't build until the project is loaded.

What is the right way to proceed here?
Should I check in `packages` or is there some other way to fetch the packages automatically (like VS did when it created my project)?

UPDATE: I was able to recover the packages directory manually using `nuget restore -SolutionDir xyz` on the command line, but is there a way to trigger this automatically before the project is opened?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Success. The condition allows the project to open, and the package is subsequently installed when I build it.

Comment: I also created a new project from scratch and found the 'Condition' attribute in the import statement so my problem must have been due to someone messing with the file manually here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the right way to proceed here?

You should add condition to the [Import target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx):

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="..\packages\xxx\xx.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xxx\xx.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

When we create the Google Test project, it imports `.targets` file to the project file `.vcxproj` by default. You can unload your project and edit it, you will following import statements:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.0\build\native\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.0\build\native\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

Not sure why the `Condition="Exists('..\packages\xx.targets')"` was lost in your import statement, to resolve this issue, please add the condition to the Import target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this in the morning. I looked through our history and could not find a Condition attribute.

Comment: I do have a  `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">` section at the bottom that contains an element called `<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.0\build\native\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.0\build\native\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.targets'))" />` -- related?

Comment: Just in case, you can move it. It used to make sure the .targets file imports successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem with adding a Google Test project. Following the Microsoft docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore mentions that actually only `nuget restore myproject.sln` and `msbuild restore` can work for `packages.config` projects like the default for a Google Test project. The following two methods worked for me:

1. `nuget restore myproject.sln`
2. `msbuild -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true -t:restore myproject.sln`

Both commands generated my packages directory with the Google Test package